# Maintain state.params between tabs react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm building an app with react-native and react-navigation.  The problem is that when I navigate to a TabNavigator view, switching between tabs erases the navigation params for the TabNavigator scene.  I want to keep the same navigation params for all the tabs.

Here is my setup.  It starts at the `Home` TabNavigator. If they click on a person in the `PeopleList`, then I navigate to the `Person` TabNavigator by calling: `this.props.navigation.navigate("Person",{person:person})`.  This defaults to the `Info` scene correctly with correct params.  However, when I click on the `PersonPurchases` tab, the `person` param is erased from the navigator state.

```
const MyApp = StackNavigator({
    Home: {screen:TabNavigator({
        PeopleList: { screen: PeopleListScene },
        Calendar: { screen: CalendarScene },
        TasksList: { screen: TasksScene },
    })},
    Person: {screen:TabNavigator({
        PersonInfo: { screen: PersonInfoScene },
        PersonPurchases: { screen: PersonPurchasesScene }
    },{tabBarOptions:{ tabBarPosition:"bottom", backBehavior:"none"})}
})
```

Any idea how to prevent this from happening?